# How can i keep a kind of nested class fields who's host class extends from a base class?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm using ProGuard to obfuscate my code. I have some class extends from BaseResponse, ScheduleResponse is one of it. And in ScheduleResponse, i have a kind of nested class, like FreeTimeResponse. Now i want to keep all those fields in nested class not to be obfuscated. In this case, is keep **calendar** and **class_place_addrlist**. Thanks

```
static class ScheduleResponse extends BaseResponse {
    static class FreeTimeResponse {
        ArrayList<Schedule> calendar;
        ArrayList<String> class_place_addrlist;

        public ArrayList<String> getAddressList() {
            return class_place_addrlist;
        }

        public ArrayList<Schedule> getSchedule() {
            return calendar;
        }
    }

    FreeTimeResponse data;

    public FreeTimeResponse getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand clearly. My interpretation is that you want fields in `FreeTimeResponse` which are accessible from `ScheduleResponse`. Am I correct ? Or do you want `BaseResponse`'s and `ScheduleResponse`'s fields to be available in `FreeTimeResponse` ? - Please improve the question description

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand. I'm using ProGuard to obfuscate my code. I have some class extends from BaseResponse, ScheduleResponse is one of it. And in ScheduleResponse, i have a kind of nested class, like FreeTimeResponse. Now i want to keep all those fields in nested class not to be obfuscated. Thanks